# Вывод всех товаров выбранного раздела

Tags: python

не могу понять как записать функцию, чтобы она выдавала чисто ключ и значение. В таком виде она выдает сразу всё.  Мне надо название товара и цену..

```
shop = {
    'одежда' :{
        'галстуки':100
    },
    'обувь': { 'кросовки': 700}
}



def print_all_product(shop = shop,):
    for key, value in shop.items():
        print(key + '- ' + str(value))

print_all_product()
```

Answer (score 1):

делайте так:

```
shop = {
    'одежда' :{
        'галстуки':100,
        'носки': 120
    },
    'обувь': { 'кроссовки': 700}
}

def print_all_product(shop = shop,):
    for key, value in shop.items():
        print(key + ' - ' + ', '.join(value.keys()))

print_all_product()
```

> Мне надо название товара и цену..

тогда делайте так:

```
def print_all_product(shop = shop,):
    for key, value in shop.items():
        for item, element in value.items():
            print(f"{item} - {element}")
```

Comment: *> Мне надо название товара и цену*

Comment: @Евгений, виноват, внёс правку

Answer (score 0):

```
shop = {'одежда': {'галстуки':100},'обувь': { 'кросовки': 700}}

def print_all_product(shop, category):
    for key, value in shop[category].items():
        print(key + ': ' + str(value))

print_all_product(shop, 'одежда')
```